# How to use DateDiff in calculated field in access

Tags: ms-access, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am trying to get "No of days late" in a particular table in MS access. I am trying to use calculated data type.

I have [ActualReturnDate] and [ReturnDate] in the same table (both are Date/Time) and I want to save difference between two columns in a calculated field.

I am using following expression:

```
DateDiff("d", [ActualReturnDate] , [ReturnDate] )
```

But no matter what i do I get error saying "The expression X cannot be used in a calculated column."

So does that mean I cannot use DateDiff in Calculated field? If not how should I do it?

Comment: Avoid using calculated columns at all, this feature is quite buggy. Use queries instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed can't do this in a calculated field.
Use a query instead, add a column and do the calculation in that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add and substract dates.

Just use `[ActualReturnDate] - [ReturnDate]` as the expression to calculate the difference. If both fields are defined as date/time, the result should be the same, only include the time part as decimal.

If you want only whole days, you can wrap the result in `Int()`